# Event listener for multiple elements, when stored as variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there a way to execute the same code for multiple elements when they are stored as variables in Jquery?

For example:

```
$('.class1, .class2').on('click', some_function);
```

when stored as variables:

```
var class1 = $('.class1),
    class2 = $('.class2);

$class1, $class2.on('click', some_function);
```

Comment: no you can't call the same function using variables with a comma ,you would have to use class1.on('click',some_function); and class2.on('click', some_function); seperately

Comment: Or `var class1 = ".class1", class2 = ".class2"; $(class1 + ', ' + class2).on(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method to the rescue!

`$class1.add($class2).on('click', some_function);`

Comment: Napierala , what is to be rescue! or rescued!

Comment: remove `$ `        ...

Comment: Yep, though even though $ should be removed in this case, JQuery variables should probably start with $ anyway. Thanks for the help!